# Convert sql results into PHP clickable link

Tags: php

I have a program where a admin can upload a image into phpMyAdmin. What I want to achieve is a page to echo out all the pictures in a table data and the picture name is another table data using sql. Clicking the name will link to another page. The problem is that each picture has different name. How do I echo the picture name into a clickable link?

```
echo "<td>";?><img src="<?php echo $row["path"];?>" height="300" width="700"> <?php echo "</td>";
```

currently this is the code that I'm getting results from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
echo "<table><tr><td><a href='YourProcessPage.php?path=" . $row['path'] . "'>" . $row['path'] . "</a></td><td><img src='" . $row['path'] . "' height='300' width='700'></img></td></tr></table>";
```

it will echo the link and the image in a table

I always use it like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($database, "YourQueryHere");
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr><td><a href='YourProcessPage.php?path=" . $row['path'] . "'>" . $row['path'] . "</a></td><td><img src='" . $row['path'] . "' height='300' width='700'></img></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>"
```

Answer (score 0):

first create a query above the table and use while statement to call all the data from the database and store it in variable and then call it on the below table

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_user_run)){
     $id = $row['id'];
     $name = $row['name'];
     $image = $row['image'];


 <tr><td><?php echo $name; ?><a href="yourlink.php?info=<?php echo $id; ?>"></a></td>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $image;?></td>
    </tr>
```